# SQL: Select all record matching value 'x', but stop when value 'y' appears

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in my table which contains the values 0 or 1.
Now I want to select the start of the last period of 1's.

Imagine I've the next table with 2 columns. The last period of 1's are the ID's 4 and 3.
The start of this period is ID = 3.

ID  -  VALUE

- 5 - 0
- 4 - 1         <-- last period
- 3 - 1         <-- last period
- 2 - 0
- 1 - 1         <-- period longer ago
- 0 - 0

But how do I select this record with one query (and maybe a bit of PHP) and without select all records?

**Edit:**

Using MySQL

Comment: what is the relationship between these tables ?

Comment: It's just one table. Id and VALUE are columns.

Comment: you want all the ids with value 1, right ?

Comment: The ID columns is in fact some kind of sequence number, ordered in time?

Comment: @MoyedAnsari No, he wants the last continuous period of 1's. In this case, I'm assuming records 4 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try finding highest id with value 1 for which closest lower id has value 0.
In sql this would be:

```
SELECT p1.id FROM periods p1
WHERE p1.value = 1
AND ( SELECT p2.value FROM periods p2 
      WHERE p2.id<p1.id 
      ORDER BY p2.id DESC LIMIT 1 ) = 0
ORDER BY p1.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql:

```
SELECT min(id)
FROM table_name
WHERE id > 3 AND value = 1
```

In your php you'd substitute the number '3' for the number which was the value you're starting with.

I believe this is the answer, though I may not fully understand your question.